# Invalid protected resource url Exception while trying to access Magento REST API using OAuth?

Tags: api, rest, oauth, magento-1.8

I'm getting the below error when trying to access `Magento REST API` in `post` method in live server.

> Invalid protected resource url, unable to generate signature base
>   string

In my localhost its working fine with same code. I'm using `oauth` authentication for REST API in `magento`. Also `GET` and `PUT` methods working fine in same server. Can anybody help me on this issue?